# How to install yql module for Python?

Tags: python, yql

I'm trying to use yql from python using "import yql".
But installing yql is failed like bellow:

```
$ sudo easy_install yql
Password:
Searching for yql
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/yql/
Couldn't find index page for 'yql' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for yql
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('yql')
$
```

So please let me know how to install yql?

Mac OS: mavericks
Python 2.7.9

Thank you in advance.

Jun

Comment: try sudo pip install yql

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are reffering to yql-finance (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yql-finance)

You could try installing it with pip.

`sudo pip install yql-finance`

note that you can also search when in doubt for the package name.

`pip search yql`

Comment: Hi @chris, "import yql" did work. As I'm referring the following URL, the yql-finance package does not contain "FileTokenStore". Do you know other yql packages?  http://tech.thejoestory.com/2014/12/yahoo-fantasy-football-api-using-python.html

Answer (score 0):

i just released a YQL Python Wrapper a couple days ago. Here are

- The Documentation http://myql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

If all you want is to use *Yahoo Fantasy Sport* you can check [Yahoo_Roster](https://github.com/almartin82/yahoo_roster_extract)

Comment: thank you for letting me know the information. I could successfully install the YQL Python Wrapper. I'll use it.